# Flatsome replacing Select Options button with Add To Cart button

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Select options appear instead of add to cart for products with variants.

How can I change the text of Select Options?

When I press Select Options, it goes to the product instead of adding it to the cart, it doesn't matter, I just want the text to change.

I have uploaded the pictures below.

[image]

Comment: You can't add to cart variable product from archive page, because you need to choose variation before adding to cart, it's default WooCommerce thing nothing to do with theme.

Comment: I solved it by adding code to function.php.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default text of "Select Options" to "Add to Cart" for WooCommerce variable products, you can use the following code snippet:

Open your WordPress dashboard and navigate to Appearance > Theme Editor.
Select functions.php file from the right sidebar to edit.
Add the following code to the bottom of the file:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_variable_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_variable_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text ) {
   global $product;
   if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $add_to_cart_text = __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
   }
   return $add_to_cart_text;
}
```

Click on the "Update File" button to save the changes.
After adding this code snippet, the text "Select Options" will be replaced with "Add to Cart" on all variable product pages in your WooCommerce store.